# CAN we call a an app on the phone and get data from it from a browser app?

Tags: android, cordova

I am on a web app that has button to invoke a scanner app on the phone. Is it possible to start scanner from web browser and get the scan results back to the page? If so, could you please provide me step by step proceedure. I looked up a lot but no success yet. Btw, the scanner app is a cordova based app that uses zxing library. Criteria met: Barcode Scanner is not allowed to use( thats the reason a scanner app using zxing is developed and is hybrid, but for now working on android.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **Camera API** to capture the Image from your phone .
2. Write the Image File which you have captured to **Web Server** So that you can View the Image in **Web page**.

Comment: How about if the data is results of scannrer by which i mean text. I have looked up but all i understood is to use callback url but im not quite sure how it works!